# Using Regular Expressions inside Lambda Functions - C#

Tags: c#, regex, lambda

I've a little test program that builds a `List` of different strings, all of which contain the same formatted number. I also then declare another list which is supposed to contain the specific numbers of each string in the former list.

My plan is to accomplish this by utilizing a regular expression match inside of a lambda function.

Every time I try and do this I get the following error:

[image]

```
List<string> newList = new List<string>(new string[] { "MyName - v 3.7.5.0 ... CPU:",
                                                           "MyName - v  ... CPU: - 1.5.7.2",
                                                           "4.21.66.2 - v  ... CPU:",
                                                           " - v  ... CPU: 31.522.9.0" });
Regex match = new Regex("(\\d+\\.)+\\d");
List<string> otherList = newList.FindAll(str => match.Match(str).Value);
```

Is there any way I can use lambda functions to accomplish this?

Comment: Well, do you understand the error? `FindAll` is expecting a predicate - something that returns true or false. `match.Match(str).Value` returns a string. Perhaps you were looking for `ConvertAll`? (Or just use `Select` and LINQ...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this:

```
List<string> otherList = newList.Select(str => match.Match(str).Value).ToList();
```

Btw, your code is failing because the predicate is expecting `bool`.

Comment: What do you mean? I thought the predicate was supposed to "essentially" assert the regex against each index in the first list, and assign that match to a spot in the new list.

Comment: Nope, check this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz(v=vs.110).aspx It will explain about Predicate class. `FindAll` is more like `Where` but they are slightly different in term of execution and performance. If you want to "transform" your collection then `select`.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm still familiarizing myself with the System.Linq library for .NET, so thank you for the pointers!

Answer (score 1):

you can try the following:
`var otherList = newList.Select(str => match.Match(str).Value);`

FindAll expects a Predicate, so you would need to do:
`newList.FindAll(str => match.IsMatch(str));`
But then you would have an `IEnumerable` that would contain the full strings and not just the numbers you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<string> newList = new List<string>(new string[] { "MyName - v 3.7.5.0 ... CPU:",
                                                   "MyName - v  ... CPU: - 1.5.7.2",
                                                   "4.21.66.2 - v  ... CPU:",
                                                   " - v  ... CPU: 31.522.9.0" });
    Regex match = new Regex("(\\d+\\.)+\\d"); 
    var result = match.Matches(string.Join(" ", newList)).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value);
```